# Pythonic way to find all elements with the highest frequency?

Tags: python, list, max, frequency

I have a list such as this:

```
lst = [1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 6, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4]
```

I would like to find ***all*** the elements which occur most frequently.
So I would like:

```
most = [1, 3, 5]
```

1, 3, and 5 would occur the most, which is 4 times. What's a fast, pythonic way to do this? I tried methods shown here:

[How to find most common elements of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594514/how-to-find-most-common-elements-of-a-list).

But it only gives me the top 3, I need all elements. Thank you.

Comment: That answer in the link does a slice `popular_words[:3]` to only return the top 3.  The actual counter contains all totals, not just the top 3.

Answer (score 10):

With [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a *list comprehension*:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 6, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4]
r = [x for x, _ in Counter(lst).most_common(3)]
print(r)
# [1, 3, 5]
```

You can generalize for values with highest count by using `max` on the counter values:

```
c = Counter(lst)
m = max(c.values())
r = [k for k in c if c[k] == m]
print(r)
# [1, 3, 5]
```

For large iterables, to efficiently iterate through the counter and stop once the required items have been taken, you can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) with `most_common` without any parameters:

```
from itertools import takewhile

c = Counter(lst)
m = max(c.values())
r = [x for x, _ in takewhile(lambda x: x[1]==m, c.most_common())] 
print(r)
# [1, 3, 5]
```

You gain by not having to iterate through all the items in the counter object, although there is some overhead with having to *sort* the items using `most_common`; so I'm sure if this *absolutely* efficient after all. You could do some experiments with [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

Comment: This is works, but I would like to find **all** elements which occur the most frequently, not just the first 3. Thank you though.

Comment: @ArjunVasudevan I've updated for a general case

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the same result with `groupby` from `itertools` module and `list comprehension` in this way:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 6, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4]
most_common = 3
final = [k for k,v in groupby(sorted(a), lambda x: x) if len(list(v)) > most_common]
```

Output:

```
print(final)
>>> [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Well, this assumes you already have a threshold a priori

Comment: Yes. It's true. However it can extended to handle all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if you like to print all the most frequent,

```
    from collections import Counter
    words=[1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 6, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4]
    most= [word for word, word_count in Counter(words).most_common()]
    print (most)
>>> 
[1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6]
```

Please note, if you want to limit, you can enter the number inside `most_common()` function. Ex: `...most_common(3)]`. Hope this answers your question.