# Python, Print most occurring words or letter from input

Tags: python

I don't know if my question is repeated or not since I couldn't really find the right answer. I wanted to print the most frequent words or numbers on a new line. However, if the frequency are the same then print both words/numbers.

```
Input: green green green orange orange yellow

Output: green


Input: green green green orange orange orange yellow

Output: green 
        orange


Input: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4

Output: 1
        2
        3


Input: 1 1 1 2 2 3 3

Output: 1
```

Comment: This is a fascinating problem statement.  Have you tried to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find most common elements of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594514/how-to-find-most-common-elements-of-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

can you tell what you have tried? follow snippet may help you a bit

```
 words = ['green', 'green','green', 'yellow']

 from collections import Counter
 counts = Counter(words)

 top = [k for k, _ in   counts.most_common(list(counts.values()).count(max(counts.values())))]
 print(top)
```

Comment: I would replace `top = [k for k, _ in counts.most_common(list(counts.values()).count(max(counts.values())))]`

Comment: @AGNGazer yes i agree, edited it

Answer (score 0):

You could also do `max` with [`key` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296755/python-max-function-using-key-and-lambda-expression), then list comprehension takes all that has the count of that, because `max` just takes one:

```
>>> words = ['green', 'green','green', 'yellow','orange','orange','orange']
>>> list(set([i for i in words if words.count(i) == words.count(max(words,key=words.count))]))
['green', 'orange']
>>>
```