# Finding the most frequent strings in a list neglecting case sentivity

Tags: python, list, case-insensitive

I have a list of Twitter hashtags named `li`. I want to make a new list `top_10` of the most frequent hashtags from that.
So far I have done ([#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3594640/7673979)):

```
li = ['COVID19', 'Covid19', 'covid19', 'coronavirus', 'Coronavirus',...]
tag_counter = dict()
for tag in li:
    if tag in tag_counter:
         tag_counter[tag] += 1
    else:
         tag_counter[tag] = 1
 
popular_tags = sorted(tag_counter, key = tag_counter.get, reverse = True)

top_10 = popular_tags[:10]

print('\nList of the top 10 popular hashtags are :\n',top_10)
```

As the hashtags are not case-sensitive, I want to apply case-insensitivity while creating my `tag_counter`.

Comment: post sample data of the `li`

Comment: when comparing, convert both strings to lower or uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize data first, with lower or upper.

```
li = ['COVID19', 'Covid19', 'covid19', 'coronavirus', 'Coronavirus']
li = [x.upper() for x in li] # OR, li = [x.lower() for x in li]
tag_counter = dict()
for tag in li:
    if tag in tag_counter:
         tag_counter[tag] += 1
    else:
         tag_counter[tag] = 1
 
popular_tags = sorted(tag_counter, key = tag_counter.get, reverse = True)

top_10 = popular_tags[:10]

print('\nList of the top 10 popular hashtags are :\n',top_10)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
Can you please tell me what `key = tag_counter.get` is doing the function `sorted()`? 
Also, how can I improve/shorten my code?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the standard library

```py
from collections import Counter

list_of_words = ['hello', 'hello', 'world']
lowercase_words = [w.lower() for w in list_of_words]

Counter(lowercase_words).most_common(1)
```

Returns:

```
[('hello', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` from collections library

```
from collections import Counter

li = ['COVID19', 'Covid19', 'covid19', 'coronavirus', 'Coronavirus']

print(Counter([i.lower() for i in li]).most_common(10))
```

Output:

```
[('covid19', 3), ('coronavirus', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

See below

```
from collections import Counter

lst = ['Ab','aa','ab','Aa','Cct','aA']
lower_lst = [x.lower() for x in lst ]
counter = Counter(lower_lst)
print(counter.most_common(1))
```